# What is the relationship between generative models and density estimation?

Tags: density-function, generative-models, density-estimation

If aren't they synonymous, what distinguishes the one from the other? Is probability density estimation a certain kind of generative model? Can any generative model be regarded as density estimation?

Answer (score 4):

Density estimation is generally seen as a nonparametric goal: rather than using specific families such as the Gamma family or the Normal family, density estimation procedures can arrive at any shape. I haven't seen anyone use the name "density estimation" for a parametric procedure, presumably because then it's just parameter estimation.

By contrast, generative models often have parametric components; for example, the Latent Dirichlet Allocation model uses the Dirichlet distribution.

Comment: Thanks. Here Prof. Ng introduces EM as a way of doing density estimation, wouldn't that be a parametric goal? https://youtu.be/ZZGTuAkF-Hw?list=PLA89DCFA6ADACE599&t=1279

Comment: I guess it's a fuzzy boundary. Nonparametric procedures sometime use mixtures of Gaussians -- just with one Gaussian per data point. They might  even be used generatively; that's sort of the idea behind the bootstrap.

I would never call LDA "density estimation", even though it can yield a density estimate.